# All possible combinations combining n lists with at least on elem of each list

Tags: list, permutation, combinatorics

with an input of n lists which may contain n elements each. i want to find all combinations which have at least one element of each input list.
example with 2 input lists of length 2

```
input 1: {1,2}
input 2: {3,4}

expected result: 
{{1,3}, {1,4}, {2,3}, {2,4}, {1,2,3}, {1,2,4}, {1,3,4}, {2,3,4}, {1,2,3,4}}
```

expandable to n input lists with n elements

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can count binary from `1` to `2^n - 1`. This for each set.
Then you select one number for each set, giving `(2^n - 1)^n` combinations.
The binary number tells you which elements to include (1) and which not(0).

In the above example (assuming that `{1, 2, 3, 4}` is indeed part of the expected result), you'll have `9 = 3^2 = (2^2 - 1)^2` combinations.

---

Because the answer didn't explain enough, a further explanation.

Let me stick to your example. We have

- 1 = 01b -> {2} for set1, {4} for set2
- 2 = 10b -> {1} for set1, {3} for set2
- 3 = 11b -> {1, 2} for set1, {3, 4} for set2

Because the 0 = 00b is omitted, it is guaranteed that at least one element from each set is chosen.

Now we pick a number for each set. That gives

(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2) and (3, 3).

If you substitute the first number with the corresponding set of elements from the first set and the second number with the corresponding elements from the second set, you'll have the desired result:

- (1, 1) -> {2, 4}
- (1, 2) -> {2, 3}
- (1, 3) -> {2, 3, 4}
- (2, 1) -> {1, 4}
- (2, 2) -> {1, 3}
- (2, 3) -> {1, 3, 4}
- (3, 1) -> {1, 2, 4}
- (3, 2) -> {1, 2, 3}
- (3, 3) -> {1, 2, 3, 4}

Basically you just count within a 2^n - 1 number system. That has digits that run from 0 to 2^n - 2. So we have 00, 01, 02, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22 which exactly corresponds to the list above, only that the digits are 1 smaller than the number they correspond to.

Comment: ur right forgot the combination {1, 2, 3, 4} (updated the question). however i dont understand how ur answer leads me to solving my problem?